# Is it possible to mix a D-Link router with other adapters since my D-Link adapter won't work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I spent several hours yesterday on line and on the phone with (very rude!) D-Link tech support only to have them tell me that something was wrong with my new Windows 7 drivers.  I am returning my D-Link adapter today.  However, I have been running this router and adapter on my other two computers running XP for quite some time with great success and don't want to (can't afford to) change all that set up.  Can I find some other adapter that will work on my new computer or is it cheaper to buy a card to put inside or another wired modem from my cable company?

Answer (score 1):

The brand of the wifi adapter does not matter. You can mix all sorts of router and wifi brands (so long as you're using the standard b/g/n speeds and not the boostmax/superboost/etc...)

Since you're having issues with your dlink adapter and windows 7. I'd suggest just going online and purchasing a

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what happened. The modem you got from your cable company is a hybrid which means is part modem and part router and then you put the CAT cable to your router. There could have happened double NATing or something else that prevented it from working fine. D-Link tech should have caught that. My preference would be just a modem (if you can get it from your cable company) and then put [Bufallo](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/routers-and-access-points/airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-essential-high-power-router-access-point-whr-hp-g300n/) router after it. All other devices should work fine with it.